# Why isn't {{ page.date }} working in my jekyll install?

Tags: jekyll

I installed my old blog on a github pages site, transferring it to jekyll from textpattern. It's in a sub-directory called `/journal`. The individual posts show the post's date no problem.

On the `/journal/index.html page, {{ page.date | date: "%x" }}` does not work at all.

What do I need to add so that the date will show up on the blog's index page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looping over your posts in `index.html` then you'll want to use the post's date instead of `page.date`. It'll look something like this:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
    {{ post.date | date: "%x" }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i changed it to `{{ post.date`  and `endfor %}`. worked perfectly. thank you! ;)